# Read an attribute of the base class using "istream" of derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix, derived-class

It looks like `Coord(a)` doesn't work , and the values for `lon` and `lat` are `00.0000` and `00.0000`, those from the default constructor . What should I do? 
Ia there a problem with the syntax ? Isn't it `in >> Coord(a)` to read `lon` and `lat` from base class?

```
 //base class
class Coord {
    private:
    double lon;
    double lat;
Coord() { lon = 00.000000000000000; lat = 00.000000000000000; }
//.....
//.....
//.....
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Coord& temp)
{
    cout << "Longitude is : "; in >> temp.lon;
    cout << "Latitude is  : "; in >> temp.lat;
    return in;
}
};

//derived class   
class Location : public Coord {
private:
    char model[6];
    double time;
    int speed;
//.....
//.....
//.....
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Location& a)
{
    cout << "Model is : "; in >> a.model;
    cout << "Time is : "; in >> a.time;
    cout << "Speed is : "; in >> a.speed;
    cout << "Coordinates : " << endl; in >> Coord(a);
    return in;
}
};
void main()
{
   Location loc;
   cin>>loc; cout<<loc;
}
```

Comment: `Coord(a)` creates a temporary?

Comment: Your minimal example is not even close to compiling.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, `Coord(a)` creates a copy (much like [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)). Your code shouldn't compile, because you're passing an rvalue to `operator>>`, which takes an lvalue reference.

You have to use `static_cast`, to get a **reference** to the `Coord` base class:

```
in >> static_cast<Coord&>(a);
```

That will make it call the right `operator>>`.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much ! But could you explain me in detail ? Does it create temporary lon and lat ?

Comment: @Mihai And what's with the `00.000000000000`? Isn't `0` enough? `double` is not `std::string`, it's going to be truncated anyway.

Comment: Yes , you are right  . Just to remember how many digits the lon and lat have , because I use setprecision()  during my program .